# Pandas, Pivot error - cannot label index with null key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which looks like below.

```
ID     Product   date
1        A     01.01.2015  
1        B     01.01.2015  
1        C     01.03.2015
```

A person can take more than one product on the same day, I want to transpose it by ID,date and get product as values.

ID         date      col1   col2

```
1      01.01.2015   A      B
1      01.03.2015   C
```

In SAS I do it like below:

```
proc transpose data = data;
  by ID Date;
  var product
run;
```

In pandas I used following code.

```
data_b = data_a.pivot(index = ['patnum','day'], values = ['drug']).add_prefix('p')
```

This is giving following error.

```
ValueError: cannot label index with a null key
```

Why I'm getting above error? How can I avoid it?

I'm using latest version in Pandas.

Comment: The `pandas` example (error supposedly your error comes out) is different from the proposed example/dataframe. Also, saying you're using the "latest version in Pandas" does not really help, give the actual version number.

Answer (score 4):

use `groupby`

***for `list` objects***

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'date'])['Product'].apply(list)

ID  date      
1   01.01.2015    [A, B]
    01.03.2015       [C]
Name: Product, dtype: object
```

***for a dataframe***

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'date'])['Product'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)

               0    1
ID date              
1  01.01.2015  A    B
   01.03.2015  C  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But why do I get the above mentioned error? what does cannot label index with a null key mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another column to identify rows within each date to help you `pivot`:

```
df.assign(Count = df.groupby('date').cumcount()).pivot("date", "Count", "Product")

#    Count  0      1
#date       
#01.01.2015 A      B
#01.03.2015 C   None
```

Answer (score 0):

A year later I have the same problem, rearranging the code to the following solved it:

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index =['coulmn1','coulmn2'])
```

being new to Python, I dont know why this works, I also dont know if its good or bad coding and nor do I know the cause of error message we both got...

Comment: I got downvoted for this, can anyone explain why? Seems a bit unfair without a reason, lost a 1/4 of points haha. Thanks

Comment: from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables): `While pivot() provides general purpose pivoting with various data types (strings, numerics, etc.), pandas also provides pivot_table() for pivoting with aggregation of numeric data.`. Probably the reason why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `DataFrame.pivot_table()` instead of `DataFrame.pivot()`

I got the same error and corrected it using above mentioned correction.

Thanks.